# Find and Replace first 100 lines that match in editplus or Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, editplus

I need to find certain characters and want to replace them only for the first 100 lines. Is there any easy way to do this in Notepad++ or editplus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notepad++ you should be able to just highlight the first 100 lines, and then do a replacement on the selection.  For instance, to replace `A` with `a`, just highlight your lines and then use:

```
Find:    A
Replace: a
```

Comment: thanks. it works! Will accept your answer in 10 min as it doesn't allows me to accept now